# R - Unable to create plot by Factors even though X is a Factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot where my X axis should be 'Default Channel Grouping' and Y should be revenue.
When I try the chart, it doesn't show the different channels even though this field is a Factor, not Characters. What could be the reason here? Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Code now updated as per correct answer from Phil

```
str(data)
data$Date<- as.Date(as.character(data$Date),"%Y%m%d")
data <- data %>%
mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)
p <- ggplot(data=data,
aes(x=`Default Channel Grouping`,
y=Revenue)) + geom_col()
p
```

[image]

Comment: Try `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`, does  that help?

Comment: Use the backticks: `aes(x=\`Default Channel Grouping\`,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aes(x=`Default Channel Grouping`. Solution provided by Phil. Code updated here.